# Beginner JS identifier error

Tags: javascript

I am getting an identifier error on the first 'else if'. How come, and why dont i get another error for the second 'else if'?

```
<p id="user"></p></p>
<p id="rock"></p>
<p id="paper"></p>
<p id="scisors"></p>
<p id="check"></p>
<script>
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
document.getElementById("user").innerHTML=(userChoice);
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice <=.3399){
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML=("rock");
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};


else if (computerChoice >=.34<.67){
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML=("paper");
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};

else if (computerChoice >=.67){
document.getElementById("scisors").innerHTML=("sciscors");
document.getElementById("scisors").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};
```

Comment: `else if (computerChoice >=.34<.67)` does not look like JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (computerChoice >=.34<.67){
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML=("paper");
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};
```

Is likely whats intended... The problem is here:

```
else if (computerChoice >=.34<.67){
```

You cant just have two operators together... You can acomplish this in two ways:

**AND Operator:**

```
else if (computerChoice >=.34 && computerChoice<.67){
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML=("paper");
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};
```

**OR OPERATOR**

```
else if (computerChoice >=.34 || computerChoice<.67){
    document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML=("paper");
    document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
    };
```

### Semi-colon Error:

```
if (computerChoice <=.3399){
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML=("rock");
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};


else if (computerChoice >=.34<.67){
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML=("paper");
document.getElementById("paper").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};

else if (computerChoice >=.67){
document.getElementById("scisors").innerHTML=("sciscors");
document.getElementById("scisors").innerHTML+=(computerChoice);
};
```

You cant have those semicolons before the else if statement as @squint said in the comments below.. Hope this helped

Comment: *"Is not javascript..."* Sure it is. It's perfectly valid syntax, though likely not what was intended.

Comment: No its not @squint i have never seen this in javascript: else if (computerChoice >=.34<.67) ... And thats not valid syntax..

Comment: Of course it's valid. Just because you've never seen it or don't understand what it does, doesn't make it invalid. However, there is some invalid code in the question that you haven't addressed.

Comment: hmm? Did i adress it now @squint ?

Comment: No, first, the operators are valid. What will happen is that the `computerChoice >=.34` will take place first, which will be `true` or `false`. So the next one will be `true < .67`, which is a valid operation in JS. The invalid code is the `;` before the `else if`s

Comment: Ok but im preety sure thats not what he intended to do @squint

Comment: And that's what I wrote in my first comment above.

Comment: Edited anwser @squint

Comment: Yep, looks better.

Comment: Thanks guys. This totally helped!